# Convert dict to list with same keys, values and layout

Tags: python, list, dictionary, extract

I´m trying to extract several keys/values out of a List.

My List:

```
a = [ 
      {
        "id": "1",
        "system": "2",
      },
      {
        "id": "3",
        "system": "4",
      }
    ]
```

Now i need to parse this into a function (**next** function) and it returns **a[current]** or **a[0]**.
But now is **a[current]** or **a[0]** a dict.

Next step is just to extract the **ID** and the value of it. But this below only works if **a** is a list! So i need to convert the **a[current]** or **a[0]** into a list. The code below has to be the same because it´s a function and if i cannot change this for several reasons, so i need to convert the dict **a** into a list **a**.

```
c = list()
for data in a:
     value = dict()
     value["id"] = data.get("id")
     c.append(value)
```

And here i stuck, i tried several methods like .keys(), .values(), but i can´t put them together to a list anymore. It needs to be scaleable/configurable because **a** changes from time to time (not a[0]["id"], ...). Currently a[0] looks like this: {'id': '1', 'system': '2'}, but it needs to be like this: [{'id': '1', 'system': '2'},], that i can parse it to my search function.

I need a new list like **c**:

```
    c = [ 
          {
            "id": "1",
          },
          {
            "id": "3",
          }
        ]
```

Comment: @Xitiz not if you run the "search lines" with a[0]

Comment: @Xitiz for data in a:
     value = dict()
     value["id"] = data.get("id")
     c.append(value) -> this code

Comment: @Xitiz i cannot change the search code with data.get("id"). So i need to change a[0] to fix it. a[0] looks now like this: {'id': '1', 'system': '2'}, but i needs to look like this: [{'id': '1', 'system': '2'},], so i can parse it to the search code.

Comment: @Xitiz yes thanks you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this your your expected output:

```py
a = [ 
      {
        "id": "1",
        "system": "2",
      },
      {
        "id": "3",
        "system": "4",
      }
    ]
    
c = list()
for data in a:
     value={}
     value["id"]=data.get("id")
     c.append([value])
     # c.extend([value])

print(c)
# [[{'id': '1'}], [{'id': '3'}]]

# print(c) # Extend's output 
# [{'id': '1'},{'id': '3'}]
```

Or you can try one-line solution

```
print([[{"id":val.get("id")}] for val in a])
# [[{'id': '1'}], [{'id': '3'}]]
```

Or as your comment if you just want

```py
[{'id': '1', 'system': '2'},]
```

Then :

```
print([a[0]])
```

Comment: Yes it is !
If you run it with a[0] instead of a in line (for data in a) it is just one square bracket, and thats exactly what i needed!

Answer (score 1):

**code updated:**

```
a = [ 
      {
        "id": "1",
        "system": "2",
      },
      {
        "id": "3",
        "system": "4",
      }
    ]
    
print([[value] for value in a ])
```

**Result:**

```
[[{'id': '1', 'system': '2'}], [{'id': '3', 'system': '4'}]]
```

Comment: Thanks, but i cannot change the "search function" for data in a:
     value = dict()
     value["id"] = data.get("id")
     c.append(value), it needs to be like this. I need to change a[0] to a type list.

Comment: @TomTom my suggestion is that you create a example output of what you want when you say ```a[0]``` as list so that everyone can help better. Currently the problem statement is unclear.

Comment: ok currently a[0] looks like this: {'id': '1', 'system': '2'} but it needs to be like this: [{'id': '1', 'system': '2'},], that i can parse it to my search function.

Comment: as mentioned by @Xitiz it should work ex : ```print([[value] for value in a ])``` will give you result : ```[[{'id': '1', 'system': '2'}], [{'id': '3', 'system': '4'}]]
```

Comment: oh my god, thank you guys very much! I tried to solve this for 2 days now, and such an easy solution ...

Comment: Great @TomTom you can close the question by marking the answer that solves your problem

Answer (score 0):

Here is a function to filter your dicts list:

```
def filter_dicts(key, a):
    return [{key: element[key]} for element in a]
```

Use it like this:

```
c = filter_dicts("id", a)
```

Note that this will cause an error if there is a dict without the specified key, which may or may not be what you want. To avoid this, replace `element[key]` with `element.get(key, None)`.

Comment: Thanks, but i cannot change the "search function" for data in a:
     value = dict()
     value["id"] = data.get("id")
     c.append(value), it needs to be like this. I need to change a[0] to a type list.